# Isset to use php variable in html form

Tags: php, html, forms, isset

I am trying to load instances from a database, to then create buttons out of them, which can be clicked to submit a form and add the name of whichever button is clicked to `$_SESSION['room']`. The buttons are displayed correctly, however, the `isset()` function is not receiving the correct data as there is no output when a button is clicked.

```
<?php    
if(isset($_GET['$room'])){
    $_SESSION['room'] = $_GET['$room'];
    echo $_SESSION['room'];
}
?>
<form method="get">
<?php
while($rooms > $count){
    $room = mysqli_fetch_row($search_rooms)[0];
    echo "<input type='submit' value='$room' name='$room'><br>";
    $count = $count + 1;
};    
?>
</form>
```

Comment: Try to remove the dollar signs from your get & session variables (you got the string $room), perhaps that causes issues

Comment: But I cannot assume that the name of the input is 'room' because it depends on the variable $room

Comment: Well, then you are talking to a variable (that should not be in quotes) that is not set, since you initialize it in the while loop

Comment: I understand that but how do I correct it?

Comment: @NorbertD use hidden fields or make the `name`  property fixed.

Comment: But the results from the database depend on a user selection, so the inputs can differ, meaning the name property cannot be fixed

Comment: @NorbertD — The value needs to differ (which it already does). The name needs to be fixed.

Comment: Why must the name be the variable? this can be any fixed name, since you only want to extract the value ($room). Multiple submit buttons with the same name doesn't matter since it only sends the clicked one

Comment: @NorbertD `echo "<input type='submit' value='$room' name='submitButton'><br>";`

Comment: @NorbertD `$_GET['submitButton'] = room_value_text;`

Comment: You're right but how do I then copy the value instead of the name?

Comment: @NorbertD — Just do what I told you to do, 15 minutes ago, in my answer. (It's the same as we've told you several times in the comments here since. Just do it. It will work.)

Comment: `$_GET['submitButton']` is the value when the form is submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> name='$room'
> ```

This appears inside a string quoted with `"` characters, so the variable will be interpolated.

This means you will end up with HTML that looks something like:

```
name='a_room_name'>
```

Meanwhile…

> ```
> isset($_GET['$room'])
> ```

… tests for submitted data from a form field with the name starts with a dollar sign. It is not a variable. You are testing for an input with `name='$room'>` … which you don't have.

---

You need to use a **fixed** name for your submit buttons.

`name='room'` and `isset($_GET['room'])` will do fine.

Comment: or simply use `$_GET[$room]`. Either way the code needs to be consistent which is the current OP

Comment: @Martin but isn't `$room` set once the form is submitted, not before, therefore it would be undefined. The OP could use hidden fields if they really wanted, which would hold the values.

Comment: @Martin — That won't work. `$room` isn't defined at that point. You'd need to hit the database, get all possible values, loop over them, and test them one by one. (Which would be stupidly complicated).

Comment: Meh, yes, you're both absolutely right... I would think if the OP wanted variable naming they can reorder the code to setout the value of room before compaing the `$_GET` data

Comment: `$room` can be set much earlier in the code, by the looks of it.

Comment: @Martin — The code shows where it is set, and that it generates a number of submit buttons in a loop. Since you don't know which one the user will click, you can't know what value to set it in at the top of the script.

Comment: It's only set with the value of `$search_rooms` but this value is not set in the code provided so the loop used is only a simple counter `($rooms > $count){...}` and neither of these values are set in the code shown either.... so in my mind there's everything to play for! `:-D`

Comment: I think this would be very simple to fix if the OP used a hidden field. I don't understand why they need both `name` and `value` property to be the `$room`.

Comment: @Script47 — They don't need a hidden field (you're overcomplicating it). They don't need the name and value to be $room (the OP is overcomplicating it). They need to name to be something fixed. They need the value to be $room. Then the submit button that is clicked will be successful and `$_GET['room']` will be the `$room` that was clicked.

Comment: @Quentin you are correct, simply the submit button needs to be modified.